# How to separate the 4.5 value in "4.5KM" and assign it to a double value in android programming?

Tags: android

> How to separate the 4.5 value in "4.5KM" to assign to a double variable?

Comment: so you found this difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a general syntax with the KM.

```
    String mDistanceString = "4.5KM";
    String mDistance = mDistanceString.substring(0,mDistanceString.length()-2);
    double distance = Double.parseDouble(mDistance);
```

Answer (score 0):

use regular expression.

```
String dist="4.5KM";
double distance = Double.parseDouble(dist.replaceAll("[^\\.0123456789]",""));
```

> New value of dist = 4.5
>
> you can use `/g` flag if you want
>
> ```
> /[^\\.0123456789]/g
> ```
>
> Match a single character not present in the list below [^\.0123456789]
>
> ```
> `\\ matches the character \ literally (case sensitive)`
>
> .0123456789 matches a single character in the list .0123456789 (case sensitive)
> ```
>
> Global pattern flags
>
> ```
> g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
> ```